# How to set linebreakmode for Android Textview embedded in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been using [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790186.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to embed an android TextView in my Xamarin.Forms application (to optimise performance)

I have the following:

```
<androidWidget:TextView Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Locations}" TextSize="12" View.VerticalOptions="Start" x:Arguments="{x:Static formsandroid:Forms.Context}" />
```

where the namespace is:

```
xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
```

and Locations is:

> Town 1 \r\n Town 2 \r\n Town 3

But the text does not wrap

So the question is how do I word wrap an Android TextView embedded in a Xamarin.Forms application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change locations like following Text

`Town 1&#x0d;&#x0a;Town 2 &#x0d;&#x0a;Town 3`

In Xamarin forms：

`\r` can be replaced by `&#x0d;`

`\n` can be replaced by `&#x0a;`

You could make a Test in your demo.

[image]

If you want to know more information about Native view, you could refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml).

Comment: I tried making the string the one suggested in this answer but it didn't have any affect. I think the issue is that the android Label is not wrapping the test

Comment: This is demo that i added the `Town 1&#x0d;&#x0a;Town 2 &#x0d;&#x0a;Town 3`,it is worked https://github.com/851265601/Demo .Can you share your demo?

Comment: Lu -MSFT I see in your sample your string is in the xaml. I am binding to a string property in my view model. So I am setting the string in the view model. Is there a way I can use your string in my view model?

Comment: I upload a new demo by your need, you can test it.https://github.com/Billycool1020/NativeViewDemo

Comment: Hi Leon, I tested the sample and it worked. I think the issue is in a third party control truncating the view. Thanks for your help on this one